# Quartz Cron Expression for Hours 3, 9, 15, 21

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I'm using the Quartz Grails Plugin and I need to schedule a job that runs at 3am, 9am, 3pm, 9pm every day. This seems like a valid cron expression:

```
* 3,9,15,21 * * *
```

But Quartz doesn't support that. Is what I need to do possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Quartz`, there is an additional position to the expression. The first one represents seconds, not minutes, as it is for unix-style cron expressions. The other issue is with quartz support for specifying day-of-week and day-of-month:

> Support for specifying both a day-of-week and a day-of-month value is
>   not complete (you must currently use the '?' character in one of these
>   fields).

This should work:

```
* * 3,9,15,21 * * ?
```

Take a look at this [guide](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) and the Quartz grails [docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/scheduling.html) for more details.

Comment: I actually did include the leading extra * but forgot to edit it in on the copy & paste. That said, it doesn't work. Here is what I get `Cron expression '* * 3,9,15,21 * * *' in the job class com.foo.submission.ProcessACORDJob is not a valid cron expression`

Comment: typically the errors are more descriptive when visible in java stack traces. you might want to try that. It might be something related this: "Support for specifying both a day-of-week and a day-of-month value is not complete (you must currently use the '?' character in one of these fields)".

Comment: The ? was the answer. Go ahead and update your answer and I'll accept it as correct. Thanks.